# How to get the filtered Recordset from an Access Form in vba?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I got a contentious form which shows 58 rows out of 14000 due to a applied filter.

I want to use the Recordset of the form to loop through all !shown! rows in a function which looks like this:

```
Public Sub stdb_addMultiAntraege(ByVal par_antraege As Recordset)
  
  Call par_antraege.MoveLast
  
  Dim rowcount As Long
  rowcount = par_antraege.RecordCount
  
  '... Some loop stuff
end sub
```

But when I try to call the function like this:

```
Call stdb_addMultiAntraege(Me.Recordset)
```

or this:

```
Call stdb_addMultiAntraege(Me.RecordsetClone)
```

the rowcount is 14000.

This:

```
Dim dRecordset As Recordset
Set dRecordset = Me.RecordsetClone
dRecordset.Filter = Me.Filter
Call stdb_addMultiAntraege(dRecordset)
```

has the same result.

So how do I get a Recordset which contains the !filtered! - means the shown - datasets, so the rowcount ist 58?

Comment: Look here " 'Now filter the Recordset to return only the customers from that city" on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-filter-property-dao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, opening the filtered recordset:

```vb
Dim dRecordset As Recordset

Set dRecordset = Me.RecordsetClone
dRecordset.Filter = Me.Filter
Set dRecordset = dRecordset.OpenRecordset

Call stdb_addMultiAntraege(dRecordset)
```